# MATLAB - How do I split a struct into smaller arrays based on a particular row in the struct?

Tags: matlab

I have a structure array of data that is a combination of data from different txt files. How do I plot rows 1-100 vs rows 101-200? Or how do I split them into their own structures? The first data point of each txt file has a specific value shared between them so it can be split this way also.

The end goal is to plot the 1st and 4th columns of the text files in one plot so if it is easier to specify the boundary where one file ends and another begins as a delimiter then plot the values either side of it, than can be done too.

I am a novice so any pointers on how to store the data in a better way would be appreciated if possible.

This is what I have so far

```
clc;

files = uigetdir('*.txt'); 
ds = datastore(files);
AllDataTable = readall(ds);

S = table2struct(AllDataTable);
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why don’t you split the table before converting to a struct? The table was introduced as a better container for applications like yours.

Comment: Further to Cris's suggestion, why convert them to a struct at all? If you have tabular data it's typically slightly simpler syntax to index a table than a struct...

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I guess I thought it would be easier to manipulate and plot, as Chris said, in separate structure arrays. Loading in the folder of files combined them into one table. E.g. File 1 is rows 1-100 and File 2 is 101-200 and I don't know how to extract as far as the row I need and plot that. The reason I suggested a delimiter was because the row splitting the files always contains the character 'E' but as for the practical application of my code the txt file may not have the exact same number of rows every time

Comment: You can also read each file in separately, using a loop. You might want to load one file and make the plot within the loop, so you don’t need to keep all data in memory at once.

Comment: So I would need to be overwriting the table in every iteration of the loop to get the new txt files data in?